# Some equations involving multiple absolute values

Tags: absolute-value

Consider the following equation:
$$|x+y^2|+|x-y^2|+|y+x^2|+|y-x^2|=a$$
I'm looking for the method for solving some problems regarding this equation, namely:
1) prove that if $a=2015$, then the equations has no solutions such that $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$;
2) prove that if $a=2112$, then the equations has even number of solutions such that $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$.
I currently have no idea how to deal with such an equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove the first part (i.e. that there is no solution for $a=2015$), note that the left hand side is always an even number. The reason is that the left hand side has 4 terms and the parity of all the terms is the same (they are either all even or all odd). The sum of 4 odd numbers is even, so is the sum of 4 even numbers.

To see that the number of solutions for $a=2112$ (or any other $a \neq 0$) is even, note that for any solution $(x, y)$, you can flip the sign of $x$ and get a new valid solution; and the same for $y$.

Comment: Amazing. So it was THAT simple? Thank you so much!